# C# WPF app does not work on another PC using SQL Server CE local database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sql-server-ce

I'm new to C# and databases. I have a WPF project that must use a local database. I used SQL Server CE local database with a `.sdf` file in Visual Studio 2010. It works fine on my computer.

But when I'm trying to open my project on another PC, the app doesn't work.

I get this error:

[image]>

My connection string is:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|../../MyDB.sdf");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you keep the .sdf on the "other" pc?  I believe you'd need to change your connection string to point to that location, instead of a generic "two folders up from where the executable is"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried your solution but still doesn't work, 
i have now following error:
The type or namespace name 'SqlServerCe' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: How are you installing your project on the other PC? Using OneClick? Ensure SQLCE Storage Engine is a dependency of your project.

Comment: I dont use any installation wizard, just downloading whole project from dropbox to other pc

Comment: You need to use some kind of installer; that is what sets `DataDirectory`. Anyone who runs your app from Visual Studio will have to install SqlCE first. Also, that connection string will open the source database; you do not want to do that.

Comment: Can you recommend any installer to install required files to client pc?

Comment: For WPF I recommend [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Problem is solved
Thank you very much @DourHighArch :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the 3.5 SP2 runtime MSI and install it on the users PC: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783

Comment: Thank you for answer :) , i used ClickOnce (suggested to me by @DourHighArch) to install 3.5 SP2 Sql Server CE on users PC.